# Ball is moving all the way to the left of the screen when I don't want it to

Tags: java

Whenever I tell the rectangle to go left, it moves al the way to the left side of the screen when I only want it to move a little bit. And whenever I tell it to move right, it wont move at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Balls {

    private static final int MOVE_SPEED_X = 2;
    private int x, y, width, height, velX, velY;
    private Rectangle rect;

    public Balls(int x, int y, int height, int width) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        velX = 0;
    }

    public void update() {
        y += 3;
    }

    public void reset() {
        y = 0;
    }

    public void accelLeft() {
        x = -MOVE_SPEED_X;
    }

    public void accelRight() {
        x = +MOVE_SPEED_X;
    }
}
```

Second Block of relevant code

```
public class PlayState extends State {

    private Paddle paddleRight, paddleLeft;
    private static final int PADDLE_WIDTH = 30;
    private static final int PADDLE_HEIGHT = 60;

    private Ball ball;
    private Balls balls;

    // bDiam stands for ball diameter

    private static int bDiam = 30;

    private int playerScore = 0;
    private Font scoreFont;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        paddleLeft = new Paddle(0, 195, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
        paddleRight = new Paddle(785, 195, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT);
        scoreFont = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 25);
        //ball = new Ball(300, 200, bDiam, bDiam);
        balls = new Balls(500, 0, bDiam, bDiam);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(MouseEvent e) {
        // bDiam = bDiam + 20;
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {

        balls.update();

        if (balls.getY() > GameMain.GAME_HEIGHT) {
            balls.reset();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onKeyPress (KeyEvent e){

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            balls.accelRight();
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            balls.accelLeft();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you "tell" it to move either left or right?

Comment: Exactly as @ScottHunter says: you need to show more pertinent code, preferably an [mcve]. And what is `update()` supposed to be doing, and why do you use a hard-coded value of 3 in that method?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I forgot to include the second block on code which is the PlayState. I used hard-coded because i'm only testing this all out.

Comment: If this is a Swing program, I don't see code that shows that you're respecting Swing threading rules. What is driving your animation? A Swing Timer (good)? A `while (true)` loop (not so good)? Again, I recommend that you create and post a [mcve].

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels this is not swing. Im using eclipse.

Comment: Sorry but this statement, `"this is not swing. Im using eclipse."`, doesn't make sense. Eclipse is an IDE, not a GUI library, while Swing, SWT, AWT are GUI libraries. Are you telling me that none of your import statements include `import javax.swing.*;` or `import java.awt.*;` something similar? You might want to double check and please get back to us. It could be that you're using only AWT and not Swing, but with your use of MouseEvent and KeyEvent, you're likely using one or the other, or some academic derivative of them.

Comment: Is there's a difference to put `x =- MOVE_SPEED_X;` and `x -= MOVE_SPEED_X;`?

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz Thank you, everything wrks as it should now. I

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm a noob at this, bear with me. So the correct answer is no I'm not using swing imports.

Comment: It's OK, but I'm looking for a more complete answer to the question: just what GUI library are you using? That has bearing on all that you do. Again, the import statements should tell you much, and you will want to share this information either here or in future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In accelLeft it should be x = **x** - MOVE_SPEED_X (and similar in accelRight)